# jQuery: Menu Slide Down on top of content, not push content down

Tags: jquery, menubar, slidetoggle

Currently this top menu which is supposed to stretch all the way across 100%, when clicked and expanded, it seems to just be sliding down and pushing the rest of the page content down.

I would like the menu to come down but instead of pushing the whole page down, just sit on top of the page and expand down how ever far necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#blurbPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    }); 
    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#blurbPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });     
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });     
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your html here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the site, and i'm thinking its just a css issue. I've created a fiddle that does what you're asking for. The panel has a position of absolute, therefore will be opened over the other element. I also changed your JS a bit. to this

```
$('#open-close-toggle').click(function(){
    $('#toggle-section').slideToggle(); 
    var buttonText = $(this).html();
    if(buttonText == "Open"){
        $(this).html("Close");
    }else{
        $(this).html("Open");
    }
});
```

[**Here is the fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xzdq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You to add a z-index and position properties to menu css.  Z-index lets the HTML know the layer position of the element.  In order for z-index to work properly, you need to specify the element position, so it knows how to handle surrounding elements.

I would try:

```
.menu{
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
```

That might work, but without seeing the HTML it is a little difficult to help.